# Proguard returned with error code 1. (com.google.android.gms)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard, android-proguard

When I want to sign (import) my project, I got this proguard error code 1 like this:

```
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateParseException
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: there were 87 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

and so this is full page of my

> proguard-project.txt

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
#-dontoptimize
#-dontpreverify

# If you want to enable optimization, you should include the
# following:
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
#
# Note that you cannot just include these flags in your own
# configuration file; if you are including this file, optimization
# will be turned off. You'll need to either edit this file, or
# duplicate the contents of this file and remove the include of this
# file from your project's proguard.config path property.

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
 native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
 public static **[] values();
 public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
 public static <fields>;
}

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version. We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
```

How do I fix this? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what is the version of play services that you are using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try to prevent play services to obfuscate form proguard.

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: there were 87 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2016-06-14 21:26:30 - myapp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

### Issues:

### From your log file, it is clear that

1. Some Jars are not available
2. Some unresolved references are there.

---

### Solution:

If you use maven and eclipse then, you need to run this following command

```
mvn eclipse:clean

mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

### For gradle and Android studio,

gradlew is not in your global path. To execute the 'clean' task (or any task for that matter) using the gradle wrapper (gradlew) in your project directory in your terminal, specify the current directory with the './':

```
./gradlew clean
```

### For gradle and eclipse:

```
gradle clean build
gradle eclipse
```

### Resource Link:

1. [Java Project + Gradle + Eclipse Integration Example](http://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/gradle/java-project-gradle-eclipse-integration-example)

### To show the jars in `build.gradle`

```
task listJars << {
    configurations.compile.each { File file -> println file.name }
}
```

Output of `gradle -q listJars`

```
> gradle -q listJars
hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
jta-1.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try update your google services with firebase sdks integration